# Is there a way in excel to add rows or move a row using a formula, vb or c#

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have an excel table with an ordered text column and a MoveToRow column. The table is in the right order but I need to space out the rows by adding empty rows between the values using a MoveToRow column.

Ex:

```
1. cat 2
2. dog 3
3. Rat  5
```

Is there a way in excel using a formula or vb or c# code to move or copy the animal field to the desired row listed in the second column?

Results:

```
1.    
2.cat    
3.dog    
4.
5.rat
```

or I can change the MoveToRow column into an InsertThisManyRowsAfter column if that is possible.

i would think something like this code the loops through an integer column that contains the number of rows to insert below the current one and if the value is 0 skip it but if the value is >=1 it inserts that number of rows. But this is not working properly its adding too many rows and all in the same range. Where is the logic not correct here?

```
Sub Test1()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim y As Integer
  Dim z As Integer
  ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  ' NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xldown)).Rows.Count
  NumRows = 100
  ' Select cell a1.
  Range("I1").Select
  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For x = 1 To NumRows
     ' Insert your code here.
     ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
     y = ActiveCell.Row
     z = ActiveCell.Value
     If z >= 1 Then
        Rows(y & ":" & y + z).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     End If
  Next
```

End Sub

Comment: *Yes, there is a way.* • If this is not the answer you expected then you asked the wrong question. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: You should also narrow your scope, to *one* language. Are you using VB? VBA? Or C#? (Hint: it *can't* be done with formula)

Comment: i updated the original post with my current code.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, given the example you posted.

```
Public Sub ReverseLoop()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r As String
Dim x As Long
Dim NumList As Variant  'Array
Dim RegExpObj As Object
Dim NumStr As Integer

Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Ctrl + Shift + End
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop Through 0-100 in Reverse Order
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1

    strIn = Range("A" & x).Value

        Set RegExpObj = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With RegExpObj
            .Global = True
            .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
            NumStr = .Replace(strIn, " ")
        End With

    Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Cells(NumStr, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

Next x

End Sub
```